# Is it possible to link to an email in a GMail delegated account

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I have an application that uses the GMail API to display the inbox of a GMail account.  Everyone viewing this application will have delegated access to this account.

I know it is possible to create a link to a particular email with this format:
`https://mail.google.com/mail/#inbox/message-id-here`.  However, clicking this link simply opens up the user's primary GMail account, not the delegated account.

Is there a way to construct the link url so it opens in the delegated account?

Comment: Have you checked the [Users.settings.delegates: create](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/delegates/create) documentation?

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 I hadn't, but I have now. I didn't see anything relevant.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @SteveGomez Unfortunately not.  I had to adopt a new paradigm to interact with GMail.  Namely: I don't.